# Is it okay to install a 15A outlet on a 20A dedicated circuit for a dishwasher?

Tags: electrical

I am putting in a dishwasher and I have a dedicated 20A circuit (*12/2, 20A breaker*).

I have 15A outlet handy.

Is it okay to install it in this application?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a 15A duplex, but not a single outlet. [NEC 210.21(B)(1) and (3)].

Edit: Sorry my answer was initially incomplete, only answering specifically what was asked. Many additional Code requirements still apply. GFCI protection (breaker, device, or receptacle) is likely required, see code references in comments to other answer.

Your added picture shows you mounted receptacle with only center screw, 406.5(C) requires receptacles mounted on covers to be mounted by more than one screw.

Also worth mentioning since the ground screw hole was empty in the first picture that the equipment ground needs to be pigtailed to the box and receptacle so both remain grounded when the cover is removed.

It does look like you are probably satisfying the 422.16(B)(2)(6) requirement that the receptacle for the DW must be in the cabinet adjacent to the DW.

Comment: Hold up.  You're saying you can put a 15A outlet on a 20A circuit?  The outlet is not rated for 20A, shouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I added a photo. It’s an outlet like this. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, NEC 210.21(B)(1) requires a single receptacle on a 20A be rated for 20A, 210.21(B)(3) says two or more receptacles says to refer to table 210.21(B)(3), which allows 15 and 20's..

Comment: That is a duplex, two receptacles.

Comment: @NoSparksPlease I was just about to write something similar.  However, you must have two or more outlets on the circuit, not a single duplex.  If the OP has two or more outlets on this circuit then he is fine.  If only one duplex (as pictured) then this violates 210.21(B)(3).

Comment: @NoSparksPlease No, a single duplex counts as one receptacle.  Maybe I misunderstand this.

Comment: @tnknepp -- nope, a duplex receptacle is two receptacles on one yoke -- 210.21(B)(3) says "two or more receptacles or outlets"

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I see.  This seems so completely backwards to me, good to know though.

Comment: @tnknepp Not the interpretation in states I've  worked,  See Article 100 definition of receptacle, last sentence,

Comment: Yeah, you can even get triplex receptacles on a single yoke (Leviton AC315/320)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'll have to remember that for the ground up/down argument.

Comment: @tnknepp yeah, just like electricians can latch onto a wrong idea and extend it their entire career, so can inspectors.  A single receptacle means a simplex (1-socket) recep.  If one of those is the only outlet, then yes, ampacity must match breaker.

Comment: @tnknepp it's the terminology for the most part that is confusing here, I think. The bit that the plug goes in is the receptacle. That is the only thing that counts as a receptacle: a set of holes for a plug. If there are two sets of holes (so, it can take two plugs), then there are two receptacles. The object that is put at various points in a circuit for electricity to be drawn out is the "outlet". Many outlets are just duplex receptacles like you have in your picture. A fixed/mounted wall light or ceiling light is also an outlet, however, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

A 15A duplex receptacle, as noted an another answer, is 100% fine. However, there **may** be a GFCI requirement, depending on your local code. If GFCI is required and your breaker has GFCI, you are all set. If GFCI is required and your breaker does not have GFCI then you will need to replace the breaker or install a GFCI receptacle (duplex 15A, duplex 20A or single 20A) here.

Comment: It's probably a situation where the receptacle attaches to a faceplate or mudring

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Good point. I updated the photos to show the faceplate. The left outlet(s) if for a garbage disposal and the right is for dishwasher. According to my research, neither needs a GFCI. Before this, they were simply directly attached via an exposed 14/2 and 12/2. Neither were GFCI-ed.

Comment: @David Any work you do has to comply with NEC adopted at the time you are doing work. Don't know what edition is locally adopted, 2014/2017 NEC 210.8(D) requires GFCI protection for receptacle and hardwired dishwasher connections, and 2020 was moved to 422.5, but relaxes the requirement by allowing non-gfci circuits if protection is provided by the appliance.  However the receptacles for DW and disposer may fall still under the within 6' from sink, but some jurisdictions (strangely) don't extend requirement through cabinet doors.